# Doc2Vec C-compiler User Warning

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, nlp, anaconda, doc2vec

hope you're having a good day.

I am trying to instantiate a Doc2Vec model by implementing the following code:

```
model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=300, negative=5, min_count=1, alpha=0.065, min_alpha=0.065)
model_dbow.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(all_data)])
```

However, this returns the following error:

> C:\Users\Joshua\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py:743: UserWarning: C extension not loaded, training will be slow. Install a C compiler and reinstall gensim for fast training.
>
> 100%|██████████| 10177/10177 [00:00<00:00, 322714.39it/s]

I tried to resolve it by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler as noted here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

However, it does not seem to help. I also tried to uninstall and re-install Gensim as was advised in the UserWarning but that also didn't help.

Any suggestions? I am unfamiliar with using C compilers so maybe I'm missing something here.

This is what it should look like if it works; refer to line 109 in the notebook: https://github.com/susanli2016/NLP-with-Python/blob/master/Text%20Classification%20model%20selection.ipynb

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How did you initially install `gensim`, and how did you uninstall-reinstall?

When you do re-install `gensim`, if you watch the output carefully, you may see a hint of what's going wrong. (The creation of the necessary C-optimizations either happens then, or does not.)

Conda *should* be taking care of this for you, and generally does an adequate job of making things work on Windows machines. (If I had to use Windows, rather than the Unixy OSes on which these packages are generally better-tested on, I'd use Conda.) So, you could also try uninstalling and reinstalling the entire Anaconda installation, after having the Windows C-compiler(s) installed.

Comment: I uninstalled by using "conda remove gensim" and then re-installed by using "conda install -c anaconda gensim". I saw no mention of any C-optimizations during the installation output, all I could see were:

gensim-3.4.0, certifi-2018.8.24, openssl-1.0.2p, conda-4.5.11, ca-certificates-2018.03.07

Comment: Nevermind it now works. I'm not sure how but my notebook now runs as it should.